# how can I send integer array in unicast example of contiki?

Tags: arrays, contiki

In the example-unicast.c program through packetbuf function, I can send
string from sender node to receiver node. Now instead of sending
string i want to send integer data array.
I was trying this packetbuf_copy()
I am using contiki 3.0.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`packetbuf_copyfrom()` works with other types of arrays, not only with strings:

```
int array[0] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
packetbuf_copyfrom(array, sizeof(array));    
...
unicast_send(&uc, &addr);
```

On receiver's side, use `packetbuf_dataptr()` or `packetbuf_copyto()` to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uip_udp_packet_send(struct uip_udp_conn *c, const void *data, int len)`. The code will be:

```
#define  UDP_PORT 1223   
uint8_t array[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
struct uip_udp_conn *unicastcon;
unicastcon= udp_new(&receiver_ipaddr,UIP_HTONS(UDP_PORT), NULL);
udp_bind(unicastcon, UIP_HTONS(UDP_PORT));
uip_udp_packet_send(unicastcon,array,sizeof(array));
```